# I stuck with this code, trying to figure out, how it should work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a poject, need it must be auto calculation.
let say  that we have uncounted hidden inputs with known same class and attr. diffrent value, attr diffrent price, price2 price 3 in a div to count

What im trying to do is to get attrs (price, priceX2, priceX3)
if the user inserted a number ex. 1 or 40, will return first input(price, priceX2, priceX3), and if its given 61 0r 70 then it will return to the third input(price, priceX2, priceX3) so on

```
<div id="countDiv">
    <input type="number" value="" id="counter" /> 
    <button id="countBtn"> Count </button>
    <input type="hidden" value="40" price="1100" priceX2="1200" priceX3="1220" class="classeid">
    <input type="hidden" value="60" price="1150" priceX2="1250" priceX3="1300" class="classeid">
<input type="hidden" value="70" price="1220" priceX2="1350" priceX3="1400" class="classeid">

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#countBtn").click(function(){
        var parentDOM = document.getElementById("countDiv");
        var classCounter = parentDOM.getElementsByClassName("classeid");
        var counter = $("#counter").val();
        for (var i = 0, n = classCounter.length; i < n; ++i) {
            var mPrice = parseInt(classCounter[i].value);
            var cPrice = parseInt(classCounter[i].getAttribute('price'));
            var cPriceX2 = parseInt(classCounter[i].getAttribute('priceX2'));
            var cPriceX3 = parseInt(classCounter[i].getAttribute('priceX3'));   
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of looking for all posibilieties of `classeid` objects, why you just don't get the one that has the same value as your `counter ` input? For example, you can get it easily with the next selector `$(".classeid[value='" + $("#counter").val() +"' ")`

Comment: need to get the attr price if #counter <= the hidden

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code help you.
Do do it dynamically it's not better to do using the Hidden field if you have more than 3 input hidden field. The logic will be different in that case.

Considering only 3 hidden input fields then code looks as below:

```
HTML Code:
provide id to the each hidden input fields as first, second and third as written in the code.
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$("#countBtn").click(function(){
    var counter = $("#counter").val();
    if(counter > 0 && counter <= 40) {
        var mprice = $("#first").val();
        var cprice = $("#first").attr("price");
        var cPriceX2  = $("#first").val("priceX2");
        var cPriceX3 = $("#first").attr("priceX3");
    }
    else if(counter > 39 && counter <= 60) {
        var mprice = $("#second").val();
        var cprice = $("#second").attr("price");
        var cPriceX2 = $("#second").val("priceX2");
        var cPriceX3 = $("#second").attr("priceX3");
    }
    else {
        var mprice = $("#third").val();
        var cprice = $("#third").attr("price");
        var cPriceX2 = $("#third").val("priceX2");
        var cPriceX3 = $("#third").attr("priceX3");
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunatly i gave the hidden inputs values and prices unknown for me, i can add attr ID for each but it still need to find out the values and prices then switch in case the value in counter is <= the first until finding the right one, so the hidden inputs can be 10 or more

Comment: @Fadi Are you aware about the number of the input hidden fields?

Comment: yes, and i have to switch between until i find the gap